# One line in a html template php string causes unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) PHP parse error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following problem. I have a wordpress loop querying two types of content; each by a foreach loop. The first foreach loop queries lat/long values for a google maps map. Due to output limitations i am only able to output the lat/long foreach loop directly in the scope of the wp loop. The second loop i have to save into a variable and output afterwards outside the wp loop into a separate div.

```
foreach($addrterms as $addrterm):
    if( $termi->term_id == $addrterm ) {
        $pinGlyphs = get_field( 'location_glyph' );
        $pinColors = term_description($addrterm, 'thelocations');
        $gmurl = get_field( 'location_url' );

        if( !empty($gmurl) ) {
           $addressTemplate .= '<article class="mapaddress" style="background-color:#'.$pinColors.'">
           <h2><span>'.$pinGlyphs.'</span>'.get_the_title().'</h2>
           <p>'.get_field( 'location_street' ).'</p>
           <p><span>'.get_field( 'location_postalcode' ).'</span> <span>'.get_field( 'location_city' ).'</p>
           <a href="http://'.echo $gmurl.'" target="_blank">'.echo $gmurl.'</a>
           </article>';             
        }
        else {
           $addressTemplate .= '<article class="mapaddress" style="background-color:#'.$pinColors.'">
           <h2><span>'.$pinGlyphs.'</span>'.get_the_title().'</h2>
           <p>'.get_field( 'location_street' ).'</p>
           <p><span>'.get_field( 'location_postalcode' ).'</span> <span>'.get_field( 'location_city' ).'</p>
           </article>';
        }
     }
endforeach
```

About the snippet. The if statement checks if the present address is selected to be displayed beneath the google maps map. Inside a glyph unique to the specific location is stored into the variable `$pinGlyphs` and a unique color into the variable `$pinColors`. Next a url is stored into the variable `$gmurl`. But there is a constraint that not every location must have an url. Next i check if the variable is filled or not with !empty.

In the case its empty the markup without an url is appended with `.=` to my template variable $addressTemplate. That works without a problem. In the case an url is entered for the specific location the first template block has an extra line in contrast to the second block:

```
<a href="http://'.echo $gmurl.'" target="_blank">'.echo $gmurl.'</a>
```

outside the containing wp loop i have placed the following snippet right afterwards:

```
<div class="addresses">
<?php if(!empty( $addressTemplate )){
  echo $addressTemplate;
}?>
</div>
```

Problem is the page doesn't render at all. For the line with the `a` element i get the following php error:

```
[08-Jul-2014 17:11:43 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/wp-content/themes/mysite/front-page.php on line 476
```

If i comment out the line with the `a` element everything works. Is there a way to get it outputting the `if ( !empty($gmurl) ) case properly. And is there also a way to make the code shorter and save a few lines instead of writing the whole markup more or less twice with only the line of the a element as difference? Best regards Ralf

Comment: don't put echo there. Echo is a command to output the parameter to the browser, but you use it in a string, which makes no sense at all. Try `<a href="http://'.$gmurl.'" target="_blank">'.$gmurl.'</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Echo command can't be used in a string. Remove the 'echo' from your code.

```
  <a href="http://'. $gmurl .'" target="_blank">'. $gmurl .'</a>
```

For better reading of the code, leave a space between the variable and the dot.